# How to set permanent iterations with angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to replicate with angular(6) an animated tree with leafs moving around in randomize spaces like visible [here](https://psyquimper.fr/)

EDIT, Solved with angular animations and a callback for when the animation ends that modify state.

Template :

```
  <span *ngFor="let leaf of animatedLeafs" 
  [ngStyle] = "{
    'height.px': leaf.height,
    'width.px': leaf.height
  }"
  [@animateLeaf] = "{
    value: statusState,
    params: {
      top: leaf.top,
      left: leaf.left,
      angle: leaf.angle,
      topDir: leaf.topDir,
      leftDir: leaf.leftDir,
      angleDir: leaf.angleDir
    }}"
  (@animateLeaf.done)="loopAnimation($event)"
  class="leaf-icon">
  </span>
```

component animations :

```
animations: [
    trigger('animateLeaf', [
      state('start-state', style({
        transform: `translate3d({{left}}px, {{top}}px, 0) rotate({{angle}}deg)`
      }), {params: {height: 0, left: 0, top: 0, angle: 0}}),
      state('loop-state', style({
        transform: `translate3d({{leftDir}}px, {{topDir}}px, 0) rotate({{angleDir}}deg)`
      }), {params: {height: 0, leftDir: 0, topDir: 0, angleDir: 0}}),
      transition('loop-state=>start-state', animate('3s ease-in-out')),
      transition('start-state=>loop-state', animate('3s ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

And in the class :

```
export class AnimatedTreeComponent implements OnInit {
  statusState = 'start-state';

  constructor() {
  }
  loopAnimation(event) {
    console.log(event.toState);
    this.statusState = event.toState === "loop-state" ? "start-state" : "loop-state" 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createLeafs()
    this.statusState = 'loop-state'
  }
```

Hope it helps some :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Angular animations, you should use [CSS3 `keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

(I'm not giving you a course on that, with 20 minutes you can understand it).

If you want to stay in an Angular context and animate in another way, you can use `ViewChildren` :

```html
<span *ngFor="let leaf of leafs" #leafs></span>
```

```js
@ViewChildren('leafs') leafs: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLSpanElement>>;
```

With those view children, you can then get the element when you call a function, for instance on `(click)`.

Finally, if you want to anymate them right on start, then you're going to need a directive.

```html
<span *ngFor="let leaf of leafs" animateLeaf></span>
```

```js
@Directive({ selector: 'animateLeaf' })
export class AnimateLeafDirective implements OnInit {
  leaf: HTMLSpanElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLSpanElement>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.leaf = this.el.nativeElement;
    /* animate */
  }
}
```